# Intermediate-Level Reference for Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have completed Group Theory from Joseph Gallian Contemporary Abstract Algebra and from I.N. Heirstein Abstract Algebra. I am highly interested in group theory and I want to study further. Can anybody please suggest some literature.

Comment: I cannot find a group Group Theory By Juoseph, but the other two are fairly basic. You will still need to stick with basic-level group theory texts, say Rose's A Course in the Theory of Groups. Other examples include Smith and Tabachnikova, and Kurzweil and Stellmacher, in addition to those in the answer below. Also, Isaacs has a recent book out.

Comment: Group theory is a big area. I am inclined to think that this question is too broad. It would be more focused if you suggested the kind of group theory which you liked, or if you specifically asked for a book which tried to give an overview of the different topics in group theory. However, possibly my interpretation of a "second book in group theory" is really that of a "third book in group theory", so I won't vote to close :-)

Comment: Actually I am a beginner, I don't know whats next. I was told that for introduction to group theory I should refer to the books I have mentioned. I completed Group Theory part from them. After solving problems from those books and realising the theory, I have gained an interest in it. I want to explore. If you can, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

2 good ones I like for finite groups in particular

- Rotman
- Dummit and Foote

Comment: Wouldn't call either of these intermediate level. These texts only cover the basics right?

Comment: @Math Rotman goes well beyond the basics. Dummit and Foote is not a Group Theory text; like Gallian, and Herstein, it is an Abstract Algebra text.

Comment: See https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/558480.An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Groups for an overview of Rotman, https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942858 for the Table of Contents.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson